# How to show the content in the dropdownlist

Tags: java, jsp

How to show the content in the dropdowlist in java script, I try the code but  the content not show... this the code below to how to show the content...

Dropdownlist1:

```
<select name="zone" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <%
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection connection1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:register");
        Statement statement2 = connection1.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultset2 = statement2.executeQuery("select zone from landamount");
    %>
    <option>--Select--</option>
    <% while (resultset2.next()) {%>

    <option><%= resultset2.getString(1)%>
    </option>

    <% }%>
</select>
```

Comment: I think I see `Java` not `Javascript` in there.

Comment: How to see in javascript in the dropdownlist

Comment: Don't you want to mess up javascript with java code? Also format the code because it's not readable.

Comment: I think problem is with your java-code

Comment: avoid scriptlets in jsp, you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22652322/1066779) answer for how to do the same without scriptlets.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Text Node between your `<option>` tag. Otherwise you will see a blank drop down list.